# Kotlin: How to get and set a text to TextView in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, textview, kotlin

I want to change text of `TextView` While click on it.

**My code:**

```
val text: TextView = findViewById(R.id.android_text) as TextView
    text.setOnClickListener {
        text.setText(getString(R.string.name))
    }
```

**Output:** I got the output but showing **use property access syntax**.

How can one do this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In kotlin don't use getters and setters as like in java.The correct format of the kotlin is given below.

```
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.android_text) as TextView
textView.setOnClickListener {
    textView.text = getString(R.string.name)
}
```

To get the values from the `Textview` we have to use this method

```
 val str: String = textView.text.toString()

 println("the value is $str")
```

Comment: As an additional hint, you can press Alt+Enter in Android Studio when on a warning to get quick actions for fixing it.

Comment: The types will be inferred also so `val text: TextView` and `val str: String` are not absolutely necessary.

Comment: I am very new to Android, but I had to use resources.getString(R.string.name)

Comment: Is it possible to set text withot ID? [My Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64714568/5995648)

Answer (score 13):

just add below line and access direct xml object

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        txt_HelloWorld.text = "abc"
    }
```

replace activity_main according to your XML name

Answer (score 8):

to set text in kotlin

```
textview.text = "write here"
```

Answer (score 6):

Find the text view from the layout.

```
val textView : TextView = findViewById(R.id.android_text) as TextView
```

Setting onClickListener on the textview.

```
textview.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View): Unit {
        // Code here.
        textView.text = getString(R.string.name)
    }
})
```

Argument parentheses can be omitted from View.setOnClickListener if we pass a single function literal argument. So, the simplified code will be:

```
textview.setOnClickListener {
    // Code here.
    textView.text = getString(R.string.name)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `textView.text` for getter and setter, ex:

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
// Set text
textView.text = "Hello World!"
// Get text
val textViewString = textView.text.toString()
```

Answer (score 4):

- go to build.gradle(:app) file

add dependencies{

```
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

- after that go to your Activity file and write this line

> import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

Done!!

now you may direct find your widget using their id.

Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29778662)

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin synthetics have deprecated therefore you can use  bindingView method. after implementing basefragment or baseActivity you can use binding as in below:

*binding.textView.text ="type your text here"*

Answer (score 3):

Yes its late - but may help someone on reference

xml with **EditText**, **Button** and **TextView**

**onClick** on **Button** will update the value from **EditText** to **TextView**

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_submit_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Look at the code do the action in your class

Don't need to initialize the id's of components like in Java. You can do it by their xml Id's

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample)

        btn_submit_id.setOnClickListener {
            txt_id.setText(et_id.text);
        }
    }
```

also you can set value in TextView like,

```
textview.text = "your value"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.MainActivity.*

class Mainactivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity)

        txt.setText("hello Kotlin")

    }

}
```

Comment: where you initialized txt??

Comment: you dont need to initialized just add kotlin plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usage"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Google "
        android:textColor="#030900"/>


usage.text="hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

findViewById(R.id.android_text) does not need typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

**For set text**

```
textview.text = "xyz"
```

**For get text**

```
val string1 = textview.text

println(string1)

String1 value = xyz
```

Answer (score -1):

The top post has 'as TextView' appended on the end. You might get other compiler errors if you leave this on. The following should be fine.

```
val text: TextView = findViewById(R.id.android_text) as TextView
```

Where 'android_text' is the ID of your textView

Answer (score -1):

This procedure works for me:

Go to build.gradle(Module:  -> after `dependencies {`
add these lines:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

You can watch the video in this [link](https://keley-blue-book.blogspot.com/2021/08/kotlin-how-to-get-and-set-text-to.html).