# Why isn't onConfigurationChanged being called?

Tags: android, orientation, kotlin, onconfigurationchanged

I'm writing a code that changes the TextView's text when the orientation is changed 
I am using the onConfigurationChanged() listener for changing the text

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)

    val orientation : Int = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
    val oTag = "Orientation Change"

    if(orientation == (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)){
        mytext?.setText("Changed to Landscape")
        Log.i(oTag, "Orientation Changed to Landscape")

    }else if (orientation == (Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)){
        mytext?.setText("Changed to Portratit")
        Log.i(oTag, "Orientation Changed to Portratit")
    }else{
        Log.i(oTag, "Nothing is coming!!")
    }
}
```

but nothing happens not even in the Log

also I have added this attribute to my Activity in manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

What am I missing here ?
also is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: In kotlin you need to use :  mytext?.text = "Changed to Landscape" rather than this  mytext?.setText("Changed to Landscape")

Comment: @TerrilThomas the issue is onConfigurationChanged fun is not called

Comment: mytext?.setText() works while being in onCreate method.
The problem is that onConfigurationChanged() is not being called

Comment: Don't use settext like this in kotlin its wrong check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096838/how-to-get-and-set-a-text-to-textview-in-android-using-kotlin/44096865?noredirect=1#comment75216911_44096865

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code to get the confi chage

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration?) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        if (newConfig != null) {
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

A couple of things to try:

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` rather than `android:configChanges="orientation"`

Ensure that you are not calling `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` anywhere. This will cause onConfigurationChange() to not fire.

Comment: This works : android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: @TerrilThomas you were right.
adding android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize to the activity in manifest makd it work.