# Android AppCompatEditText,AppCompatTextView, setText without ID

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml, androiddesignsupport

I have simple Login page with some textview and edittex and i set static text to textview and hint to edittext from string.xml working fine.

But Now

i am receiving that strings(which i set form stirng.xml as i explained above) form webservices and i have to set webservice string.

Issue is i didn't set any id to that login screen elements(edittext and textview).

**Update**

I have AppCompatTextView like below in my XML

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/login_text_welcome"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextLightGrey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textview_size_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I want to settext to above AppCompatTextView without ID.

***Is it possible to setText to textview and edittext without setting any id?***

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findViewByName` rather than `findViewById` and then continue with your code.

Comment: you have to find views by identifier when dealing with XML

int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", context.getPackageName());
View view = findViewById(id);

you can find more on this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831506/find-view-by-name/31042515

Answer (score 0):

Just include **android:id="@+id/textView1** in your XML to set ID of an element.