# How to declare textview inside a function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, textview

So I have this function below and I want to declare a textview inside it, however using `findViewById` seems not working. What should I do so I can declare a textview inside a function?

```
fun addingNewText(idt: Int): TextView {
            //val newtext = findViewById(R.id.idt) as TextView        
            val parameter = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)    
            //newtext.setLayoutParams(parameter)      
            //newtext.tag = idt.toString()
            //return newtext
}
```

Comment: Not enough information ...Where are you trying to access `findViewById()` - Activity, Fragment etc..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin: How to get and set a text to TextView in Android using Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096838/kotlin-how-to-get-and-set-a-text-to-textview-in-android-using-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you want to create a new TextView. Like most classes, you can just call its constructor. for example:

```
val newtext = TextView(this)
```

(`this` here is a context, for example an Activity)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying create a new view you should use Ivo's answer, Or if you're trying get view in a layout, you should use `val newtext = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.idt)`. Because in kotlin you have to infer what type of view you are trying retrieve.
Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950401/not-able-to-findviewbyid-in-kotlin-getting-error-type-inference-failed) thread for more clearance.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? and explain what are you trying todo in detail.

Comment: What are passing to the TextView's constructor? @PleaseDon'tBanMe

Comment: You don't have to replace `this`. Just input the word `this`. Because Views require an activity class as a context and you pass your current activity as context using the Kotlin keyword `this`. @PleaseDon'tBanMe

Comment: Are you extending any Activity class @PleaseDon'tBanMe?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the entire kotlin class instead of the `addingNewText` function? @PleaseDon'tBanMe